# Determine if the following function is periodic & tentukan periodenya

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions

how to determine if the following function is periodic, and if so how to determine its period.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos \frac{n \pi x}{l} .....(1)
\end{equation}

I know that the function f(x) is periodic if f(x+T)=f(x) for every x; where T is the period of the function f(x). I can solve that the period of \begin{equation}
\cos \frac{n \pi x}{l}
\end{equation} is \begin{equation}
\frac{2 l}{n}
\end{equation} but don't understand the problem (1) above.

*I'm studying fourier series*

wait, latext

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What can you say about 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos \frac{n \pi (x+2l)}{l}$ ?

Comment: \begin{equation}
\cos \frac{\pi x}{l}+\cos \frac{2 \pi x}{l}+\cos \frac{3 \pi x}{l}+\ldots+\cos \frac{n \pi x}{l}
\end{equation}

@geetha290krm

Comment: Hi, maybe you could use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro) to evaluate the sum and then try to check whether it is periodic or not…

Comment: $\frac {n\pi (x+2l)} l=2n\pi +\frac {n\pi x } l$.

Answer (score 0):

This statement you made is not the full story:

> the function $f(x)$ is periodic if $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for every $x$; where $T$ is the period of the function $f(x)$.

The full story is:

> the function $f(x)$ is periodic if $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for every $x$; where $T$ is **a** period of the function $f(x)$.

Periodic functions actually have infinitely many periods. If $T$ is a period of $f$, then $$f(x + 2T) = f((x + T) + T) = f(x + T) = f(x)$$
So $2T$ is also a period of $f$. And an almost identical calculation shows that $3T$ is also a period, and so on. If $T$ is a period of $f$, then so is $kT$ for any positive integer $k$.

Now if $f$ is continuous and periodic but not constant, there has to be a smallest period, and that is the one we normally call **the** period of $f$. But it is useful to keep in mind that all the multiples of that value are also periods.

Next note that if two functions $f$ and $g$ both share a common period $T$ then so does any operation applied to them. If $F(x,y)$ is any function of two variables, then
$$F(f(x+T),g(x+T))= F(f(x), g(x))$$

The same holds true for any number of arguments, even infinite, provided the individual functions are all periodic with the same period $T$.
$$F(f_1(x+T), f_2(x + T), f_3(x + T), \dots) = F(f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x), \dots)$$

The summation in your problem is a function $F$ of infinitely many variables. So if you could find a *common* period for all of the $\cos \frac{n\pi x}l$ functions being added, it would also be a period for their sum.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @WillSherwood - Either you are joking, or you haven't understood at all my point. If the latter, then I must bear some responsibility for having failed to be clear enough. But even so, this is an answer, not a comment - whether you can recognize it as such or not. It is true I have not simply written out the answer, but I practically rubbed your nose in it.

Comment: I'm not joking - your answer is not specific enough to the class of functions listed in the question, and it is not general enough to solve the problem over all classes...

Comment: What you wrote basically amounts to "To find the period of a sum of periodic functions, find the common period amongst them!"

Comment: Plus a bunch of facts about periodic functions, which are not only trivial in hindsight, but I would actually say are just straight up trivial..

Answer (score 0):

You are summing functions of period $2\ell$, $\ell$, $2\ell/3$, $\ell/2$, $2\ell/5$, and so on. Notice that each of these evenly divide $2\ell$. Hence, the period of $f$ is $2\ell$.

Comment: Note that as originally stated, the sum actually diverges. But if you divide each summand by $n$, you will get the desired result.

Comment: So, as written, your $f$ is not a function and hence not periodic. If you write $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{\ell}\right)$, then the periods of the summands do not change, but now $f$ converges, so the period of $f$ is $2\ell$.